# Conjugacy classes of $GL(4,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, general-linear-group

I have the following question from a past Algebra qualifying exam:

> Let $G=GL(4,\mathbb{C})$ be the group of $4\times4$ invertible matrices with complex entries. List in a precise way the conjugacy classes of $G$.

We call two matrices $A$ and $B$ similar if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $$A=PBP^{-1}.$$
It seems like I'm supposed to be using some result about similar invertible matrices that I don't seem to be familiar with. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Are you familiar with Jordan normal form?

Comment: @Servaes I am. I remember a result that said something like the Jordan normal form exists if and only if the characteristic polynomial splits over $\mathbb{C}$ (in this case). But $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed so this is always true. So does this reduce my problem to partitioning the set of all upper triangular matrices into conjugacy classes since every complex valued matrix is similar to one?

Comment: Two matrices are conjugate over $\Bbb C$ if and only if they have the same JNF (up to reordering of blocks).